# With Storm, is there significant benefit to anchoring my tuples in this case?

Tags: apache-storm

During my stream my tuples do not split in anyway. One action is eventually performed out for each tuple in.

I can still fail them if they run into some sort of exception that they might conquer if replayed by my `KafkaSpout`. Though, I don't know how my spout knows which tuple to replay when they're not anchored, but in testing it seems to replay the right one. Is this expected, the `KafkaSpout` implementation tracks tuples/messages in some way I'm not aware of? Am I possibly anchoring an not realizing it (my bolts extend `BaseRichBolt`)? Possibly I'm just mistaken that it replays the correct one?

But if manually failing does work, then I believe the only benefit I get from anchoring is that my tuple will be replayed when it times out -- which I'm not sure is worth the overhead of anchoring.

Am I correct about this? Is there some other significant benefit to anchoring in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BaseRichBolt` does not do any anchoring automatically (`BaseBasicBolt` would do this). Thus, the behavior you describe should only work if you have simple *Spout -> Bolt* topology. For deeper topologies, ie, *Spout -> Bolt1 -> Bolt2*  and no anchoring in Bolt1, failing of tuples in Bolt2 cannot work.

Using `KafkaSpout` each tuple emitted gets a `MessageId` assigned, thus fault-tolerance mechanism is activated. Thus, each tuple must get acked in the first Bolt receiving those tuples; otherwise, the tuples time-out eventually. Tuples emitted in Bolt1 should get anchored (otherwise, those tuples get not tracked, cannot fail---neither manually in Bolt2 or per time-out---and cannot get replayed in case of failure).

Thus, anchoring is a pure fault-tolerance mechanism. You should actually always anchor tuples because anchoring itself does not **enable** fault-tolerance; assigning `MessageId`s in Spout **does enable it**. If a Bolt processes a tuple that does not have an ID assigned, the anchoring call will do "nothing" and the overhead of an additional method call is tiny. Therefore, adding anchoring code is usually a good choice, because the Bolt can be used with or without fault-tolerance enabled (depending if the Spout assigns messaged IDs or not). If you omit the anchoring code, fault-tolerance will break in this Bolt and downstream tuples cannot get recovered on failure.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the detailed answer. Basically, I was mistaken in thinking that my failed tuples wore being replayed properly without anchoring.